# SPFx: pnp.sp.search how to get only list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

I made search in SPFx, now i need to display only list items. My code example:

```
pnp.sp.search({
        Querytext: query,
        RowLimit: 20,
        StartRow: 0,
        QueryTemplate: "contentclass:sts_listitem"
    });
```

But I get not only list items.

Answer (score 1):

Only **sts_listitem** would not sufficient because document is also considered as ListItem in SharePoint as we can still set metadata there.

Possible solution could use **STS_ListItem_GenericList** which will gives returns result from only custom lists.

Make sure that by using **STS_ListItem_GenericList**, it will not give result from special list types e.g. Events, Tasks, Discussion Boards, Announcements, etc. So if you want result from those special lists as well then you can add all possible option in query template.

You can find possible option [here](http://balaonweb.blogspot.com/2012/01/types-of-content-search-scope-rule.html). (Unfortunately I couldn't find any official link from Microsoft)

So based on above, below code would give you result from all custom lists and also from all contact lists.

```
pnp.sp.search({
    Querytext: query,
    RowLimit: 20,
    StartRow: 0,
    QueryTemplate: "(contentclass:STS_ListItem_GenericList OR contentclass:STS_ListItem_Contacts)"
});
```

You can add additional condition based on your requirement with OR condition in **QueryTemplate**

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following code to using pnp.sp.search :

```
import { spfi } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/search";
import { ISearchQuery, SearchResults, SearchQueryBuilder } from "@pnp/sp/search";

const sp = spfi(...);

// text search using SharePoint default values for other parameters
const results: SearchResults = await sp.search("test");

console.log(results.ElapsedTime);
console.log(results.RowCount);
console.log(results.PrimarySearchResults);


// define a search query object matching the ISearchQuery interface
const results2: SearchResults = await sp.search(<ISearchQuery>{
    Querytext: "test",
    RowLimit: 10,
    EnableInterleaving: true,
});

console.log(results2.ElapsedTime);
console.log(results2.RowCount);
console.log(results2.PrimarySearchResults);

// define a query using a builder
const builder = SearchQueryBuilder("test").rowLimit(10).enableInterleaving.enableQueryRules.processPersonalFavorites;
const results3 = await sp.search(builder);

console.log(results3.ElapsedTime);
console.log(results3.RowCount);
console.log(results3.PrimarySearchResults);
```

More information for reference: https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/search/

*Note: Microsoft is providing this information as a convenience to you. The sites are not controlled by Microsoft. Microsoft cannot make any representations regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any software or information found there. Please make sure that you completely understand the risk before retrieving any suggestions from the above link.*